# How to trim the large number(130 digit) to 40 digit in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to trim the number to 40 digit, but getting below error:

Query:

```
select 1123123211231231231231231231231231231123123123123123123123213213123213123213123123213123123123123213123123123126666666355555899 from dual;
```

**Error**:

```
ORA-01426: numeric overflow
01426. 00000 -  "numeric overflow"
*Cause:    Evaluation of an value expression causes an overflow/underflow.
*Action:   Reduce the operands.
Error at Line: 14 Column: 8
```

Comment: You can't trim the number (130 digits) as it doesn't exist. Oracle has no numeric data type allowing 130 digits. Do you mean a 130 chars long string?

Comment: What do you mean by "trimming a number"? There is no such thing. If you believe there is, please explain it on small enough numbers. For example, take the number 148. What do you mean by "trimming 148 to two digits"? I've been a mathematician all my life, but never heard of anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, perhaps? Enclose it into single quotes (so that it becomes a string) and apply `SUBSTR` to it:

```
SQL> select substr('1123123211231231231231231231231231231123123123123123123123213213123213123213123123213123123123123213123123123126666666355555899', 1, 40) result from dual;

RESULT
----------------------------------------
1123123211231231231231231231231231231123

SQL>
```

Comment: This changes the magnitude of the number.

Comment: That's how I understood the question, @MT0.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string and `TO_NUMBER( value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR )`:

```sql
SELECT TO_NUMBER( value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR )
FROM   long_numbers
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE long_numbers ( value ) AS
SELECT '1123123211231231231231231231231231231123123123123123123123213213123213123213123123213123123123123213123123123126666666355555899' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '112312321123123123123123123123123123112312312312312312312321321312321312321312312321312312312312321312312312312666666635555589' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> |                                                                                                          TO_NUMBER(VALUEDEFAULTNULLONCONVERSIONERROR) |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------: |
> |                                                                                                                                                  null |
> |                        112312321123123123123123123123123123112300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
> | .0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000123456789012345678901234567890123456789 |
> ```

**Why doesn't the first value work?**

From the [Oracle data types documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832):

> The following numbers can be stored in a `NUMBER` column:
>
> - Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10<sup>-130</sup> to 9.99...9 x 10<sup>125</sup> with up to 38 significant digits
> - Negative numbers from -1 x 10<sup>-130</sup> to 9.99...99 x 10<sup>125</sup> with up to 38 significant digits
> - Zero

So your first example will not work as it is outside the limits that the `NUMBER` data type can accept. There is nothing that can be done to display it as a `NUMBER` as it is too big.

**What can I use instead of a `NUMBER` data type?**

If you require the exact value then you will need to store it as a string.

If you want an approximate numeric value then you can store it as a `BINARY_DOUBLE`:

```sql
SELECT TO_BINARY_DOUBLE( value )
FROM   long_numbers
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | TO_BINARY_DOUBLE(VALUE) |
> | :---------------------- |
> | 1.1231232112312312E+126 |
> | 1.1231232112312312E+125 |
> | 1.2345678901234568E-110 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e89132b053dcbf75c4cb70c6be18751a)*